# EPA Air Markets Program Data (AMPD) - API, Scrape, or Automate Browser? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to query and download csv files from the following website on a regular basis:

http://ampd.epa.gov/ampd/

I want to automate this process and am aware that the EPA has an API for developers, but it does not include the above data set in particular (as I understand it).  Didn't see anything particularly illuminating here either:

http://data.gov/

One cannot simply download using requests or urllib, because the data only appears to be accessible through a web application with a static base address.

So is the best/only solution to automate a browser using Selenium?  Or do other approaches exist?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is splinter as well, read about phantomjs - it is a headless browser.

Comment: What are the costs/benefits of splinter vs selenium?

Comment: You can find here information about splinter, if i'm not wrong splinter is a wrapper for selnium, means it's kind of the same https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with this data before, and found that they have an FTP site: ftp://ftp.epa.gov/dmdnload/.  Does this contain what you're looking for?  For data like that on hourly emissions, it's possible to automatically construct the URLs (year + state + month) and then download directly via wget, curl, etc.